# Substitute rigid body simulation in Bullet Physics?

Tags: c++, simulation, bulletphysics, rigid-bodies

I want to create my own rigid body simulation algorithm inside Bullet Physics engine. Is there a way to replace the btrigidbody integration with mine, but still maintaining the rest of the simulation (collision detection, contact response, etc) ?

I just want to compare different integration algorithms (explicit euler, implicit, runge-kutta, etc)

I though of inheriting from btRigidBody, but the problem is that the methods of btRigidBody are not virtual, so my methods are not being called.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `btRigidBody`?  Is that a reference to a class in some library?

Comment: Read the title. I will edit the text anyway.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I thought "Bullet Physics" was the physics of a bullet.

Comment: Thats ok. Its just that their forum is really bad, and I'm forced to ask these questions here.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own constraint solvers. Custom constraint solvers will allow you to define your own physics along side those of the basic Bullet implementation.

I don't think you want to override the Rigid Body object itself, as that may have side effects.

see the ref: http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/BtContactSolverInfo

Comment: Wow, that seems much more complicated than I thought. I'll study it though. Thanks very much!

Comment: What exactly is the end goal of comparing these? I just spent months porting a physics engine and optimizing it for parallel computing. It is all pretty complex, which is why I ask.

Comment: I'm trying to create my own framework for my portfolio, but I didn't want to start from scratch. That is why I am using Bullet. By the way, I am not sure that a constraint solver is going to work to solve my problem. Wouldn't it be called only when there are contacts or some constraint is being violated?

Comment: Yeah, i guess if you're after integration, you'd fundamentally have to  change the dt calculations. That should be part of the main cycle for the engine, no?

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. Maybe I could just copy/paste btRigidBody and create my own class, which inherits form btCollisionObject? Although I think I would have to change much more things...

Comment: Yeah, there's the whole set of dependencies. What worries me is that degenerate penetration calculations may not jive with the force integration, leading to an unstable model. From my experience, many things can lead to unstable models.

Comment: I think the easiest thing to do is to go into the btRigidBody.h and change it to virtual. That way I can inherit from it.